# positioning breaks design fixed vs relative

Tags: html, css

So i have a menu line on top of the screen, and after that i have an logo, which is coded as background image. So the problem is, if i put `#mobile_menu`->`position:relative;` everything is fine, and logo is after the menu block, but if i put the menu as `position: fixed;` which i have to, then logo slides up and menu covers that logo. 
I cant put padding to logo, because it don`t work.

```
<div id="mobile_menu" class="hide_menu">
  //menu elements
</div>

<header id="header" class="calign group">
  <a id="logo" class="png ru" href="page">name</a>
</header>
```

Comment: A JS Fiddle would be quite handy, as would the relevant CSS.

Comment: i will try to make it happen, moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically i solved this issue by adding a another div, and outside div i put `position:relative;` and inside div i added `position:fixed;` everything now is fine